# How do I make underscores visible again in Eclipse?

Tags: ide, eclipse, text-editor

After upgrading my workstation from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 I found that all the underscore _ characters in my C and C++ code were invisible withing the Eclipse editor.  This means that `function_name` and `Class_Name` started displaying as `function name` and `Class Name`; although the _ character was still clearly there based on the syntax highlighting and the results of pasting into gedit.

Comment: I assume you've already turned off GTK3?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Not as far as I am aware.  I did the upgrade.  Resumed work.  Noticed this issue.  Scratched my head.  Googled.  Came here after some attempts to fix it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some searching for "Invisible underscore character Ubuntu" lead me to some old posts that indicate it is the user of the 'monospace' font within the Eclipse editor that causes the problem.  This can seemingly affect almost any application and is not limited to the Ubuntu distribution.  At certain font/display sizes the underscore character becomings invisible.

To resolve this in Eclipse, you need to set a different default font for it to use.  Go to `Window > Preferences` then select `General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts`.
To change the font used by default click the 'Edit Default...' button.
To change just the C/C++ font select `C/C++/Editor/C/C++ Editor Text Font` and click the 'Edit...' button.
Clicking either button will bring up a font selection window, in which there should be several other monospaced fonts for you to choose from.  Selecting some of the other monospace fonts resolves this issue for me, but keeps the code looking aligned.

Comment: I simply reset the "Text editor" font to the default and this was resolved for me.

Comment: If the "Text editor" is used as the default for all the specialised editors that should help me and anyone else who sees this issue in make, java, Ruby and other file types.

Comment: In version 2018-12, there is no Edit Default button.  Instead, select Basic-->Text Font in the Colors and Fonts window, and then click "Edit..."

Answer (score 15):

In ubuntu 16.04 we had same problem with Monospace 14, changing size fixed the problem (i.e. 15 in our case)

Comment: I spent an hour looking for the hidden logic why whitespaces were converted to underscores, somewhere in a large Java project. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Under Window->Preferences then 
General->Appearance -> Colors and Fonts . 
Then Edit Button (defaults to "Basic. Aa Text Font")

I changed to Ubuntu_mono
and worked. 
Though font visually was smaller on screen so changed to 12 from 10

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a particular font that's decent